# I get stack overflow when instantiate a class inside WPF MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, stack-overflow

When i create an instance of a class and call a method from it, I get stack overflow error! Actually i want to prevent writing whole my code inside the MainWindow, so i need to separate them into different classes.

This is my custom class (class2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class Class2
    {
        private string[] names = { "USA", "Canada", "China", "Peru", "Germany" }; // really simple array
        MainWindow mn = new MainWindow(); // Main window instance

        public void lbxm() // this method shows array element inside a listBox
        {
            ListBox lbx = new ListBox() { Width = 200 };
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                lbx.Items.Add(names[i]);
            }

            mn.grd.Children.Add(lbx); // place the listBox in Main grid layout
        }
    }
}
```

This is MainWindow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); // here's the problem, i get stackoverflow exception...
            Class2 cl2 = new Class2(); // instance of class2
            cl2.lbxm();// call the method
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Class2` instantiates a new `MainWindow`, which instantiates a new `Class2`, which instantiates a new `MainWindow`... Think about what object should own what.

Comment: Do not add Items in code behind. The proper way of populating a ListBox in WPF is to bind its ItemsSource to a collection of data items. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new instance of `Class2`, you're also creating a new instance of `MainWindow`:

```
class Class2
{
    private string[] names = { "USA", "Canada", "China", "Peru", "Germany" }; // really simple array
    MainWindow mn = new MainWindow(); // Main window instance <- this is the problem
    ...
}
```

The problem is when `Class2` creates a new `MainWindow`, the new `MainWindow` then creates a new `Class2`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent(); // here's the problem, i get stackoverflow exception...
    Class2 cl2 = new Class2(); // instance of class2
    ...
}
```

This new `Class2` then creates ANOTHER `MainWindow`, and the cycle repeats until stack overflow. Even if this code did not create a loop that caused a stack overflow, this code would still not work the way you want. The `MainWindow` you're creating in `Class2` is not the main window your application created: it's a brand new `MainWindow` object.

If you need your `Class2` to update objects in `MainWindow` (which may not be the best way to solve this problem depending on your use case), I would pass the control to the class instead of giving the class a reference to its parent. Something like this would work:

```
//In Class2
public void PopulateListBox(ListBox grd) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        grd.Items.Add(names[i]);
    }
}
```

To call the method:

```
//In MainWindow
Class2 cl2 = new Class2();
cl2.PopulateListBox(grd); // pass the ListBox where you want the items.
```

As I mentioned, there are likely better ways to solve this problem than passing a control to a class. This couples your classes to your UI, which in general is not desirable. But this basically does what you wanted your original code to do.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce your code behind to this:

```
class Class2
{
    public string[] Names { get; } = { "USA", "Canada", "China", "Peru", "Germany" };
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Class2();
    }
}
```

`public string[] Names` is now a property, to which you bind the ItemsSource property of a ListBox in XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"/>
```